# JS function without arguments is working. How?

Tags: javascript

While I browse for some JS Code, I found the code.

Sample code:

```
arg = "TEST ALERT MESSAGE";
MyFunction(arg);

function MyFunction()
{
alert(arg)
}
```

Above MyFunction() is given the alert message, but there is no parameter to receive the incoming arugment.

But when I change the 'arg' variable(in the function and out side the function 'arg'), it is not working.

How it is possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If `MyFunction` does not have a local version of `arg`, it will try refer to a property named `arg` in the outer scope. Failing that you will get `undefined`.

Comment: A function without any pre-defined arguments can still take arguments, they are dynamic and can be accessed through the `arguments` pseudo array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable scope in javascript doesn't work the way you think. 
 in order to make that variable 'private' try:

```
var arg = "not private";
function privateMSG(){
var arg = "private";
  function alerter(){
  alert(arg);
 }
  alerter();
}
```

[MDN has a much better explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope) in the **Nested functions and closures** section

Comment: Actually they do. But their scope is chained with the one they are defined in. Variable lookups will start in the function's scope and if they cannot be resolved there, the lookup will proceed along the chain, finally ending up with undefined if found nowhere.

Comment: is this power of javascript or any like bug?. I thought there is no security

Comment: It's by design. You use closures to make stuff private.

Comment: Now I can understand. Thanks Friends